# Mysql: Select all orders from today (converting unix timestamp)

Tags: mysql, unix

I'm trying to write a mysql query to get all orders that have been placed today. But I'm having a lot of trouble with this because my database uses unix timestamp to store the date.

I have been able to convert this to a more human-readable date with the following but the WHERE clause does not work.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`entryDate`), '%Y-%m-%d') as entryDate, id FROM customers_orders WHERE entryDate = CURDATE()
```

This returns zero results, and I don't know why. When I run the query without the WHERE I get results.

I have created a SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93f02/13 (but it's offline right now...)

I've also tried;

```
SELECT CURDATE()
// Output: 2013-10-30 (own database)
// Output: October, 30 2013 00:00:00+0000 (SQLfiddle)
```

Not sure why it returns differently on SQLfiddle but that is solve-able using;

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') 
// Output: 2013-10-30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`entryDate`), '%Y-%m-%d') as entryDate, id 
FROM customers_orders WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`entryDate`), '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Thanks! So the `as entryDate` is just being ignored?

Comment: expression used in select does not work in where clause. That way you are getting problem.